# bash, regex, return the matched regular expression(s)

Tags: regex, bash

Please point out to me how to get bash to print for me a matched expr like `(?<=id=)[0-9]`.

I'd also like the input to come from the pipe, and it will be a single line of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to print solely the matched expressions
(not the entire line, several expressions within the same line may be displayed)

```
yourcommand | grep -P -o '(?<=id=)[0-9]'
```

Answer (score 2):

bash's regular expressions aren't Perl-compatible. You could use grep:

```
grep -P -o '(?<=id=)[0-9]'
```

And in a pipeline:

```
number=$(echo "foo id=3 bar" | grep -Po '(?<=id=)[0-9]')
echo $number  # => 3
```